# HTML 5 acces and handle iphone flashlight

Tags: javascript, html, telerik, flashlight

I want to acces iphone flashlight automatically.
There are many sample javascript plugin but does not work.

I download [this](https://github.com/Icenium/sample-flashlight/tree/master/sample-flashlight) sample

to my web [site](http://www.awaspi.com/a/index.html).I opened [this url](http://www.awaspi.com/a/index.html) with iphone
 there is a button "Turn ON Flashlight"
i click that it does not do any thing

i want to access device flashlight and handle it and open it automatically

Answer (score 0):

That plug in is for cordova, http://cordova.apache.org/

Its a tool to build hybrid applications so you can write HTML5 code and build it into a native app and thus having access to native features like the camera.